# Qt setStyleSheet performance

Tags: qt, optimization

In my Qt GUI, I have a lot of code which updates stylesheets every n milliseconds based on boolean value, like this:

```
void MainWindow::_update_lock_elements()
{
    if(backend::i().get_controller().is_control_locked()){

        ui->lockInfoLabel->setText("CONTROL GUI");
        ui->lockButton->setEnabled(false);
        ui->lockInfoLabel->setStyleSheet("background-color: #35BC19");
        ui->lockButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: green");
    }
    else{
        ui->lockInfoLabel->setText("MONITORING GUI");
        ui->lockButton->setEnabled(true);
        ui->lockInfoLabel->setStyleSheet("background-color: #FF8888;");
        ui->lockButton->setStyleSheet("");
    }
}
```

I have noticed this to hog up a lot of cpu power. If I cache the last value for the if condition, and only set the style sheets if the value has changed with respect to the last value, the performance is improved massively.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this in Qt so I don't have to cache and compare the last values everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no. Setting stylesheets is not cheap. Better avoid using them if possible especially for frequent interface updates.

What I do in such cases - create a state machine and change GUI only at state transitions. In general, this is still comparing last values, but in a more organized way.

AFAIK, the only way to make a GUI application use less CPU is to minimize draw calls. This is not a videogame, we do not need to redraw the whole screen every frame. That is why the signal/slot system is so well suited for Qt - everything is driven by events, not periodically.